# image not displaying in django admin site

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
projectDirPath = path.dirname(path.dirname(__file__)) 
storeImageDir = FileSystemStorage(location=projectDirPath + '/couponRestApiApp/stores')

class stores(models.Model):
    """ This is the store model """
    storeName = models.CharField(max_length=15)                                          # Store Name
    storeDescription = models.TextField()                                                # Store Description
    storeURL = models.URLField()                                                         # Store URL
    storePopularityNumber = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)                            # Store Popularity Number  
    storeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",storage=storeImageDir)            # Store Image 
    storeSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)                                         # This is the text you see in the URL
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                  # Time at which store is created
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                      # Time at which store is updated
    storeTags = models.ManyToManyField(tags)                                             # All the tags associated with the store

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.storeName)

    def StoreTags(self):
        return '\n'.join([s.tag for s in self.storeTags.all()])
    def StoreImage(self):    
        return '<img src="%s" height="150"/>' % (self.storeImage)
    StoreImage.allow_tags = True
```

But image is not loading on the admin page and the image URL is : `http://localhost:8000/admin/couponRestApiApp/stores/static/mcDonalds.jpg/`

is showing but the correct path should be: `/home/vaibhav/TRAC/coupon-rest-api/couponRestApi/couponRestApiApp/stores/static/mcDonalds.jpg/`

Where should the images must be stored so that they will be displayed on the Django admin Page

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/couponRestApiApp/stores/static/mcDonalds.jpg/
stores object with primary key u'static/mcDonalds.jpg' does not exist. This error is displaying whenever i tried to open the image..

Comment: Why do you use `upload_to` and `FileSystemStorage` together?

Comment: If there is another way of doing this then do tell...

Comment: What is the django version you are using?

Comment: Django version : (1, 4, 5, 'final', 0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in your settings properly.

#### settings.py

```
import os
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8'))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'media').replace('\\','/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

#### models.py

```
storeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': False}),
)
```

Try using the above code.

---

Answer for question asked in comment:

's' is being added to the model name, since there will be multiple model instances. To get rid of it, define `verbose_name` for the model.

```
class stores(models.Model):
    .....
    storeName = models.CharField(max_length=15) 
    .....

    class Meta:
        verbose_name        = 'Store'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Stores'
```

Comment: I tried solution by mentioning : MEDIA_URL = '/stores/images/' and MEDIA_URL = '/media/' but not working..

Comment: Try adding the above url pattern in your `urls.py`.

Comment: You solution is working but how to stop url back tracing i mean. Anyone can see all the files in the uploaded folder...how to stop that

Comment: In the url pattern, specify `'show_indexes': False` instead of `True`. This will prevent showing file indexes.

Comment: Thanks man actually i am new to Django so i am still learning...thanks for the help...

Comment: Why 's' is appending to the model name in django admin site is their any way of getting rid of it..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28292/discussion-between-arulmr-and-user2217267)

Answer (score 2):

As per Django documention, for Django 1.11 and above you will need to rewrite:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

call global url in your HTML code
like {{name.store.url}}
it should be done on your HTML code