# Images not showing in Django Admin

Tags: django

I am trying to add an a view for the uploaded images in admin, I have written the following but nothing is showing

Here is the model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    design = models.ImageField(
        blank=False, null=True, upload_to=upload_design_to)

    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src"{}" height="50"/>'.format(self.design.url))

    image_tag.short_description = 'Design'
```

here is the admin

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['image_tag']
    list_display = ['designer','image_tag']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16030430/7541313) for the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is a typo in here, you missed a `=`:

```
def image_tag(self):
    return mark_safe('<img src"{}" height="50"/>'.format(self.design.url))
                              ^^^^
```

Fix it by:

```
def image_tag(self):
    return mark_safe('<img src="{}" height="50"/>'.format(self.design.url))
```