# I think my url path and code is correct but still why images are not showing in admin panel

Tags: python, django

You can see in the image the product image is not displaying:

[image: You can see in the image the product image is not displaying]

My `models.py`:

```
# from email.policy import default
# from pyexpat import model
from django.db import models
# from unicodedata import decimal
from shortuuid.django_fields import ShortUUIDField
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from userauths.models import CustomUser

STATUS_CHOICE=(
    ("process", "Processing"),
    ("shipped", "Shipped"),
    ("delivered", "Delivered"),
)

STATUS=(
    ("draft", "Draft"),
    ("disable", "Disable"),
    ("rejected", "Rejected"),
    ("In_review", "In Review"),
    ("published", "Published"),
)

RATING=(
    (1,"⭐☆☆☆☆"),
    (2,"⭐⭐☆☆☆"),
    (3,"⭐⭐⭐☆☆"),
    (4,"⭐⭐⭐⭐☆"),
    (5,"⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐"),
)
# Create your models here.

def user_directory_path(instance,filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class Category(models.Model):
    cid=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="cat",alphabet="abcdef")
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Food")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="category",default="category.jpg")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Categories"

    def catagory_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50"/>'%(self.image.url))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Tags(models.Model):
    pass

class Vendor(models.Model):
    vid=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="ven",alphabet="abcdef")


    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Nest")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path,default="vendor.jpg")
    description=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,default="Normal Vendorco")


    address=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="6,Dum Dum Road")
    contact=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="+91")
    chat_resp_time=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")
    shipping_on_time=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")
    authenticate_rating=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")
    days_return=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")
    warranty_period=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="100")


    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Vendors"

    def Vendor_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50"/>'%(self.image.url))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    pid=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="prd",alphabet="abcdef")


    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    cagtegory=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)


    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Apple")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path,default="product.jpg")
    description=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,default="This is a product")

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=1.99)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=2.99)

    specifications=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # tags=models.ForeignKey(Tags, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)

    product_status=models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=10,default="In_review")


    status=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    in_stock=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    digital=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    sku=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="sku",alphabet="abcdef")

    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Products"

    def product_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50"/>'%(self.image.url))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_percentage(self):
        new_price=(self.price/self.old_price) * 100
        return new_price

class ProductImages(models.Model):
    images=models.ImageField(upload_to="product-image",default="product.jpg")
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Product Images"



######################################################Care,Order,CartItemsand Address###########################

class CartOrder(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,default="1.99")
    paid_status=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    order_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    product_status=models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICE, max_length=30,default="prodcessing")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Cart Order"

class CartOrderItems(models.Model):
    order=models.ForeignKey(CartOrder,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice_num = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    product_status=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    qty=models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default="15")
    total= models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default="20")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Cart Order Items"

    def oder_img(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="/media/%s" width="50" height="50"/>'%(self.image))


###########################Product Revew, wishlist, Address############################################

class ProductReview(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    review=models.TextField()
    rating = models.BigIntegerField(choices=RATING, default=3)

    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Product Reviews"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title

    def get_rating(self):
        return self.rating



class wishlist(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="wishlists"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title



class Address(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    status=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Address"
```

**in my admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from core.models import *

# Register your models here.


class ProductImagesAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model= ProductImages

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[ProductImagesAdmin]
    list_display=['user','title','product_image','price','featured','product_status']

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['title','catagory_image']

class VendorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['title','Vendor_image']

class CartOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['user','price','paid_status','order_date','product_status']

class CartOrderItemsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['order','invoice_num','product_status','item','image','qty','price','total']

class ProductReviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['user','product','review','rating','date']

class wishlistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['user','product','date']

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['user','address','status']

admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category,CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Vendor,VendorAdmin)
admin.site.register(CartOrder,CartOrderAdmin)
admin.site.register(CartOrderItems,CartOrderItemsAdmin)
admin.site.register(ProductReview,ProductReviewAdmin)
admin.site.register(wishlist,wishlistAdmin)
admin.site.register(Address,AddressAdmin)
```

Please check out my problem. I think my code is correct but in the image that I send you can see that images are not displaying in product image column. What is going wrong? All the tables are working properly also I can upload products.But the problem is only with the image. I go to inspect mode and see the required image size but still not working. Please help me out!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [image not displaying in django admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030139/image-not-displaying-in-django-admin-site)

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)